# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `number` supplied to `TextInput`, expected `string`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

in react-native, I have:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `number` supplied to `TextInput`, expected `string`.
```

I have a `postalCode` and it is numeric value.

I have set the [`keyboardType="numeric"`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype) on `<TextInput />` but I still have this error on ios/android/web.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just convert your number to a string

```
<TextInput value={postalCode.toString()} ...
```

Comment: that's what I did, and I also convert it back before submitting it. but that's not a valid answer as this is not explaining why this is happening and how to fix this.

Comment: An InputText is always text, but can set the keyboardType to Numeric to prevent the user from typing non numeric characters (on ios and android, this will display a numeric keyboard). But that doesn't change the fact that TextInput is internally text based

Comment: I'm reading the doc of TextInput and it seems that onChange and onChangeText both return a string, is there any other callback that returns a number?

Comment: Actually setting your keyboardType to numeric won't prevent you from pasting non numeric characters

Answer (score 6):

Changing `keyboardType` to `numeric` doesn't make your `TextInput` to accept only numbers, it only changes the layout of the keyboard on your mobile device. With `keyboardType=numeric` your keyboard will have only digits to make it easier for user to type numbers, it's a UX thing but it doesn't make your `TextInput` of type numeric, that's why you're seeing this warning.

Comment: make sense. I wasn't sure why at first. But then, I set my Input with ```keyboardType={'number-pad'}``` and get this warning.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is in the `onChange` callback.

You can call the onChangeText method like that:

`onChangeText: (text) => setValue(text)`

Hope it works!